# classifier predict_proba returns 1 and 0 only

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am trying to build a MultiLabelClassification model for a dataset which includes text fields (description) as well.
For the text fields I am using TfIdfVectorizer and creating a column for each word. Even after stemming and using stop words, I have thousands of rows (for each textfield, I create a new TfIdfVectorizer) 
As a result of having so many columns, with DecisionTreeClassifier model I have the predict_proba function returns only 1's and 0's as probability scores. 
The part of my code which I build the vectors is as follows

```
descVectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', lowercase=False, max_df=0.95, stop_words=stop)
temp = list(descVectorizer.fit_transform(data['description']).toarray())
textData = pandas.DataFrame(temp, columns=descVectorizer.get_feature_names(), index=data.index)
temp=None
print(3)
nameVectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', lowercase=False, use_idf=False, stop_words=stop)
temp2 = list(descVectorizer.transform(data['name']).toarray())
nameData = pandas.DataFrame(temp2, columns=descVectorizer.get_feature_names(), index=data.index)
temp2=None
```

later on, I append nameData and textData to the actual data frame

I couldn't think of a way to reduce column numbers, any suggestion on handling text fields is welcome
Thanks in advance